# How does XCode decide what's a resource and what's not?

Tags: ios, resources, copy

I have vertex and pixel shaders in my iPad app.

*one* of the vertex and pixel shader pairs (the one that "came with" the default GL game app example) copies down to the iPhone just fine.  I noticed that one of them is marked "application" in Finder and in XCode (even though it's just a plain text file).

The other shader (that I added to the project myself) doesn't.

[I tried cleaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718677/xcode-not-copying-latest-resource-file-to-iphone) but it still won't copy the file.

How can I make my shader files go down to the iPhone simulator?  They don't seem to be going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the "Copy Bundle Resources" settings in your **Build Phases** screen for your target, these represent the list of files copied to your app bundle.